# Refused to execute script from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-functions.js

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am a beginner in this area and still studying in a college.

I am making an app for school project and

I am using firebase and trying to use firebase cloud function and messaging.

So I tried to get a token through a cloud function but when I call the function from app, I get this message.
I googled for a couple of hours and tried many kinds of ways but I still could not find the solution.

I got this error message when I run the code:

[image: I got this error message when I run the code.]

This is a html script code:

[image]

This is the code where I call the function:

[image]

Comment: The file `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-functions.js` doesn't exist as you can see from the `404` error in console. Are you sure that's the way it should be imported.

Comment: @web-nomad yes I followed google instruction... thou

Answer (score 0):

Try `text/javascript` instead of `application/javascript`.

Keep in mind that the "type" attribute is required in HTML 4, but optional in HTML5.

Comment: I tried that before and did not work! But thank you for answering!

Comment: Well, then just remove it. As I mentioned you dont need the attr type in HTML5.